# Determining confidence interval with a specified certainty for a probability of a set of outcomes.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to calculate the confidence interval for the expected outcome in what I think is a non-binomial experiment.

---

I have at 21 possible outcomes, let's call them A-U, of an event.

I have so far taken 1442 measurements, which I intend to continue adding to indefinitely, with the results so far being as follows:

```
    Q   Frequancy
A   122 8.46%
B   227 15.74%
C   247 17.13%
D   191 13.25%
E   119 8.25%
F   147 10.19%
G   166 11.51%
H   131 9.08%
I   88  6.10%
J   0   0.00%
K   2   0.14%
L   1   0.07%
M   1   0.07%
N   0   0.00%
O   0   0.00%
P   0   0.00%
Q   0   0.00%
R   0   0.00%
S   0   0.00%
T   0   0.00%
U   0   0.00%
```

I am trying to figure out how to calculate a confidence interval for each of A-U, with a chosen confidence level of 99.9%. I intend to eventually have many more measurements.

To clarify, I intended to ask what method I should use to calculate the confidence interval of each of A-U? Is it valid to treat each possible outcome as it's own set of Bernoulli trials (that is, calculate the confidence of the probability of A treating A vs not A as the Bernoulli trial, then doing the same with B, C, D, etc) for the purpose of calculating a confidence interval?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. I have some  questions. Your 'expected p' seems to be a count $Q$ divided by $1442.$ Is that right? // In a chi-squared test, you'd need observed and total counts, and from some other source you'd have expected counts based on a hypothetical value of $p$ for each category. Please  **edit your question** be be clear about what data you have and about what analysis you may have in mind. If you're planning a test, what is the null hypothesis.

Comment: @BruceET I have changed the label of 'expected p' to 'frequency' in order to be more accurate. Sorry for the mistake.

I am trying to calculate the probability of any given outcome (A-U) to the event and want to calculate a 99.9% confidence interval. In essence, what I am trying to do can be likened to rolling an intentionally unbalanced die with 21 sides and trying to figure out what the odds of it landing on a given side are.

I would welcome a recommendation as to how to edit the question and would be happy to provide more clarification!

Comment: You want twenty-one 99% confidence intervals?

Comment: @BruceET I think so? Essentially I want to be able to say "I am 99% confidant that the probability of outcome A happening is somewhere between a given two values, the probability of B is somewhere between a given two values, the probability of B is somewhere between a given two values etc. I am sorry if this is a confusing way to ask how to do that.